# Inserting elements of one list into another list at different positions in python

Tags: python, list, insert

Consider the two lists:
`a=[1,2,3]`
and
`b=[10,20,30]`,
and a list of positions
`pos=[p1,p2,p3]`
giving the positions that the elements of `b` should take in the final list of 6 elements given by the union of `a` and `b`, where `p1` is the position of `b[0]=10`, `p2` is the position of `b[1]=20` and `p3` is the position of `b[2]=30`.

What is the best python approach to this problem?

Comment: Please give an example of input and output. Note that python indexing is zero based

Comment: Where do the elements of the 'a' list come into play?

Comment: I see your comments. Thank you, I will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the output list by extending it with slices of `a` and appending the next item of `b` where needed:

```
def insert(a, b, positions):
    # reorder b and positions so that positions are in increasing order
    positions, b = zip(*sorted(zip(positions, b))) 

    out = []
    a_idx = 0
    it_b = iter(b)
    for pos in positions:
        slice_length = pos - len(out)
        out.extend(a[a_idx:a_idx + slice_length])
        out.append(next(it_b))
        a_idx += slice_length
    out.extend(a[a_idx:])
    return out
```

An example:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[10,20,30]
pos=[0, 1, 5]

insert(a, b, pos)
# [10, 20, 1, 2, 3, 30]

pos = [0, 2, 4]
insert(a, b, pos)
# [10, 1, 20, 2, 30, 3]

pos=[5, 3, 0]
insert(a, b, pos)
# [30, 1, 2, 20, 3, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, that I find useful. However I see that the ```pos``` list must be ordered. I would actually consider the case where the positions are not given in a particular order.

Comment: You just need to sort both lists simultaneously at the start of the function, see the edited code and last example.

Comment: oh great solution! I was trying, also, to use the ```sort``` function, but it is not as elegant as your one-line solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the indices and values into a dictionary, you can then loop over the range of the combined lengths. If the index is in the dict, use the value, otherwise take the next value from `a`:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [10,20,30]
pos =[2,0,5]

p_b = dict(zip(pos, b))
it_a = iter(a)

[p_b[i] if i in p_b else next(it_a) for i in range(len(a) + len(b))]

# [20, 1, 10, 2, 3, 30]
```

You will need to insure that the lengths of the arrays and the positions all make sense. If they don't you can run out of `a` values which will produce a `StopIteration` exception.

You use a defaultdict for similar approach, which simplifies the list comprehension at the expense of a slightly more complicated setup:

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [1,2,3]
b = [10,20,30]
pos =[4,0,2]
it_a = iter(a)

d = defaultdict(lambda: next(it_a))
d.update(dict(zip(pos, b)))

[d[i] for i in range(len(a) + len(b))]
# [20, 1, 30, 2, 10, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks a very elegant way. I will try it!